# Java maze DFS Nullpointer-Exception

Tags: java, maze

I'm trying to program a maze generator in Java using the `DFS-Algorithm`.
But I ran into a problem. Whenever I run this program, I get a `Nullpointerexception`, because the `Stack.pop` call returns null at some point (because it gets empty). I couldn't find my error but maybe I'm just too tired :P

The code:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Stack;

    public class FieldGenerator {

    public static Cell[][] getField(int width, int height){
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int total = width * height;
        Cell[][] retField = new Cell[height][width];
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                retField[y][x] = new Cell(cellstate.UNWALKABLE, x, y);
            }
        }
        int xStart = rand.nextInt(width);
        int yStart = rand.nextInt(height);
        Cell currentCell = retField[yStart][xStart];
        currentCell.setCell_state(cellstate.STARTINGPOINT);
        Stack<Cell> stack = new Stack<Cell>();
        stack.setSize(total);
        int visited = 1;
        while(visited < total){
            List<Cell> neighbourList = getNeighbours(currentCell, retField, width, height);
            if(neighbourList.size() > 0){ //1 or more neighbours with walls intact
                Cell randNeighbour = neighbourList.get(rand.nextInt(neighbourList.size()));
                clearWallBetween(currentCell, randNeighbour, retField);
                stack.push(currentCell);
                currentCell = randNeighbour;
                visited++;
                if(visited >= total)
                    currentCell.setCell_state(cellstate.ENDINGPOINT);
            }else{
                currentCell = stack.pop();
            }
        }
        return retField;
    }

    private static List<Cell> getNeighbours(Cell searchCell, Cell[][] searchField, int width, int height){
        List<Cell> retList = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        int x = searchCell.getx();
        int y = searchCell.gety();

        if(findCellByCoordinates(x, y-2, width, height, searchField) != null && findCellByCoordinates(x, y-2, width, height, searchField).getCell_state() == cellstate.UNWALKABLE){ //Top
            retList.add(findCellByCoordinates(x, y-2, width, height, searchField));
        }
        if(findCellByCoordinates(x-2, y, width, height, searchField) != null && findCellByCoordinates(x-2, y, width, height, searchField).getCell_state() == cellstate.UNWALKABLE) { //Left
            retList.add(findCellByCoordinates(x-2, y, width, height, searchField));
        }
        if(findCellByCoordinates(x+2, y, width, height, searchField) != null && findCellByCoordinates(x+2, y, width, height, searchField).getCell_state() == cellstate.UNWALKABLE) { //Right
            retList.add(findCellByCoordinates(x+2, y, width, height, searchField));
        }
        if(findCellByCoordinates(x, y+2, width, height, searchField) != null && findCellByCoordinates(x, y+2, width, height, searchField).getCell_state() == cellstate.UNWALKABLE) { //Bottom
            retList.add(findCellByCoordinates(x, y+2, width, height, searchField));
        }

        return retList;
    }

    private static Cell findCellByCoordinates(int xcoord, int ycoord, int width, int height, Cell[][] field){
        if(xcoord >= width || xcoord < 0 || ycoord >= height || ycoord < 0) {
            return null;
        }else{
            return field[ycoord][xcoord];
        }
    }

    private static void clearWallBetween(Cell cell1, Cell cell2, Cell[][] field){
        cell2.setCell_state(cellstate.WALKABLE);
        int x = ((cell1.getx() + cell2.getx()) / 2);
        int y = ((cell1.gety() + cell2.gety()) / 2);
        field[y][x].setCell_state(cellstate.WALKABLE);
    }

}
```

Comment: See [Stack#setSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#setSize%28int%29).

Comment: Hey @Kenney. The problem is, as soon as I remove the Stack.setSize, I'll get an EmptyStackException. Somehow my algorithm isn't correct and it pops Cells from the stack until the Stack is empty. So there has to be an error in my algorithm

Comment: Indeed.. If you change the `2`'s into `1`'s in `getNeighbours` it works fine though. I can post my working example if you like.

Comment: The reason I use + and - 2 is because I want to use this together with an A*-Algorithm and for that it needs cells which are unwalkable/walls. I  used this "Maze" to test the A*-Algorithm:
http://puu.sh/jhmLd/76919047b2.png
And the raw txt file looks like that: http://puu.sh/jhmPo/3287ba9cf4.png

Comment: Allright, looks nice! So your neighbours are not direct neighbours (which are never visited). I suggest guarding the `stack.pop()` with an `stack.isEmpty()` and abort with a "dead end" condition, because whether the current cell has any unwalkable neighbours is not directly related to the stack size. Also you are only looking for walls and breaking them, so if you start in the middle of a 3x3 `O` region the algorithm will fail immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Thanks to Kenney for helping me.
I added a "dead end"-condition and now it works like a charm!
Here the full source of the  working class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;

public class FieldGenerator {

private int _width;
private int _height;
private Cell[][] _field;

public FieldGenerator(int width, int height){
    _width = width;
    _height = height;
    _field = new Cell[height][width];

}

public Cell[][] getField(){
    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int total = _width * _height;
    for(int y = 0; y < _height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < _width; x++){
            _field[y][x] = new Cell(cellstate.UNWALKABLE, x, y);
        }
    }
    int xStart = rand.nextInt(_width);
    int yStart = rand.nextInt(_height);
    Cell currentCell = _field[yStart][xStart];
    currentCell.setCellstate(cellstate.STARTINGPOINT);
    Stack<Cell> stack = new Stack<Cell>();
    int visited = 1;
    while (visited < total){
        List<Cell> neighbourList = getNeighbours(currentCell);
        if(neighbourList.size() > 0){ //1 or more neighbours with walls intact
            Cell randNeighbour = neighbourList.get(rand.nextInt(neighbourList.size()));
            clearWallBetween(currentCell, randNeighbour);
            stack.push(currentCell);
            currentCell = randNeighbour;
            visited++;
            if(visited >= total)
                placeEndPoint(findCellByState(cellstate.STARTINGPOINT));
        }else{
            if(!stack.isEmpty()) {
                currentCell = stack.pop();
            }else {
                placeEndPoint(findCellByState(cellstate.STARTINGPOINT));
                return _field;
            }
        }
    }
    return _field;
}

private List<Cell> getNeighbours(Cell searchCell){
    List<Cell> retList = new ArrayList<Cell>();
    int x = searchCell.getx();
    int y = searchCell.gety();

    if(findCellByCoordinates(x, y-2) != null && findCellByCoordinates(x, y-2).getCellstate() == cellstate.UNWALKABLE){ //Top
        retList.add(findCellByCoordinates(x, y-2));
    }
    if(findCellByCoordinates(x-2, y) != null && findCellByCoordinates(x-2, y).getCellstate() == cellstate.UNWALKABLE) { //Left
        retList.add(findCellByCoordinates(x-2, y));
    }
    if(findCellByCoordinates(x+2, y) != null && findCellByCoordinates(x+2, y).getCellstate() == cellstate.UNWALKABLE) { //Right
        retList.add(findCellByCoordinates(x+2, y));
    }
    if(findCellByCoordinates(x, y+2) != null && findCellByCoordinates(x, y+2).getCellstate() == cellstate.UNWALKABLE) { //Bottom
        retList.add(findCellByCoordinates(x, y+2));
    }

    return retList;
}

private void placeEndPoint(Cell startcell){
    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int startx = startcell.getx();
    int starty = startcell.gety();
    int geny = 0;
    int genx = 0;
    do{
        genx = rand.nextInt(_width);
        geny = rand.nextInt(_height);
    }while((startx == genx && geny == starty) || _field[geny][genx].getCellstate() == cellstate.UNWALKABLE);
    _field[geny][genx].setCellstate(cellstate.ENDINGPOINT);
}

private Cell findCellByCoordinates(int xcoord, int ycoord){
    if(xcoord >= _width || xcoord < 0 || ycoord >= _height || ycoord < 0) {
        return null;
    }else{
        return _field[ycoord][xcoord];
    }
}

private Cell findCellByState(cellstate searchstate){
    for (int y = 0; y < _height; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < _width; x++) {
            if(_field[y][x].getCellstate() == searchstate){
                return _field[y][x];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void clearWallBetween(Cell cell1, Cell cell2){
    if(cell2.getCellstate() != cellstate.STARTINGPOINT || cell2.getCellstate() != cellstate.ENDINGPOINT)
        cell2.setCellstate(cellstate.WALKABLE);
    int x = ((cell1.getx() + cell2.getx()) / 2);
    int y = ((cell1.gety() + cell2.gety()) / 2);
    _field[y][x].setCellstate(cellstate.WALKABLE);
}

}
```